# Getting the row of a NSButtonCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have a NSTableView that contains a NSButtonCell in one of the columns. I can set up the action that is called when the button is clicked in Interface Builder fine, but I can't find anyway to determine which row in the table that the button exists in. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cell for a particular column is reused throughout the whole table so there isn't one cell per row by default. You can get the the row that was clicked on though in your action method by sending the `clickedRow` message to the cell's table view.

```
NSInteger clickedRowIndex = [tableView clickedRow];
```

Comment: this does not work, because clicking on the button gives a row of -1,  apparently because the button is not part of the row,  although is ought to be.